Getting error while setting tanstack-react-router
I am trying to build an application with vite-react with typescript, tanstack-react-router. In this application there is the sidebar area that has Links for different routes and on the app.tsx file I am listening to the different routes. But I am facing error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'undefined')
    at build (@tanstack_react-router.js?v=c69e40f0:1759:59)
    at buildWithMatches (@tanstack_react-router.js?v=c69e40f0:1808:22)
    at Router.buildLocation (@tanstack_react-router.js?v=c69e40f0:1849:14)
    at @tanstack_react-router.js?v=c69e40f0:3508:33
    at commitHookEffectListMount (chunk-NRYBWBEN.js?v=46f70afc:16913:34)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (chunk-NRYBWBEN.js?v=46f70afc:18154:19)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (chunk-NRYBWBEN.js?v=46f70afc:18127:17)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (chunk-NRYBWBEN.js?v=46f70afc:18117:15)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects (chunk-NRYBWBEN.js?v=46f70afc:18107:11)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (chunk-NRYBWBEN.js?v=46f70afc:19488:11)

This is my router tsx file
import { createRouter, createMemoryHistory, Outlet, Navigate } from '@tanstack/react-router';
import useUserStore from './store/store'; 
import Login from './pages/Login';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Leaderboard from './pages/Leaderboard';
import About from './pages/About';

const ProtectedRoute: React.FC<{ children: React.ReactElement }> = ({ children }) => {
    const { username } = useUserStore();
    return username ? children : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};

const RootLayout: React.FC = () => (
    <div>
        <Outlet />
    </div>
);

// Create the router instance
const router = createRouter({
    history: createMemoryHistory(),
    routes: [
        {
        path: '/',
        element: <RootLayout />,
        children: [
            {
            path: 'login',
            element: <Login />,
            },
            {
            path: 'home',
            element: <ProtectedRoute><Home /></ProtectedRoute>,
            },
            {
            path: 'leaderboard',
            element: <ProtectedRoute><Leaderboard /></ProtectedRoute>,
            },
            {
            path: 'about',
            element: <ProtectedRoute><About /></ProtectedRoute>,
            },
        ],
        },
        {
        path: '*',
        element: <Navigate to="/login" replace />,
        },
    ],
});

export default router;

In this on const router I am encountering Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'routes' does not exist in type 'RouterConstructorOptions<AnyRoute, TrailingSlashOption, Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>>'.ts(2353)
I have tried many things but I am new with tanstack-react-router so I am not understanding the error.
